# Add new data point in R plotly boxplot

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, boxplot

I got a boxplot in R plotly and i want to add one point in a different color.
I'm able to add the point but its to far away from my boxplot because it creates a new trace (as shown in the picture).

So i want to add the point to the boxplot without a new trace.

Thanks for your help.
My code i tried below:

```
plot_ly(data=histo, x =hist_out$baseRent, type = 'box',hoverinfo = 'x')%>%
  layout(hovermode = 'x',showlegend = FALSE)%>% 
  add_trace(x = c(ceiling(prediction_rf2())),type = 'scatter',mode='markers',text = "My new point")
```

[image: The orange point ist my new data point. I want to add this point without a new trace.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the trace name (Y), even if you have one category, for example:

```r
library(plotly)

mtcars %>% 
    plot_ly(x = ~mpg, y = "trace_0", type = "box", hoverinfo = 'x') %>% 
    layout(hovermode = 'x',showlegend = FALSE) %>% 
    add_trace(x = 30, type = "scatter", mode = 'markers')
```

[image]